# Understanding uniqueness of inverses

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, inverse

For concreteness, I'm going to work with $n \times n$ matrices (but this is also applicable to group). If I write down a matrix $A$ and an inverse $A^{-1}$, would it be correct to say that this notation is well-defined only if the inverse of $A$ is unique? That is, I could in theory have matrices $B$ and $C$ such that $AB = BA = I$ and $AC = CA = I$, but if I use this "unifying" notation, uniqueness is immediately implied.

On the same notation, if I prove that $(AB)(B^{-1} A^{-1}) = (B^{-1} A^{-1})(AB) = I$, is it enough to say that "this matrix fulfills the definition of an inverse and therefore $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$, or do I need to say, "this fulfills the properties of the inverse, and there is exactly one inverse, so this is equal to that inverse"?

Comment: Matrix inverses are always unique (if they exist)

Comment: @naslundx Though I know that to be true, is it true a-priori? That typically isn't an axiom, so I don't know if I can (or should) use the notation $A^{-1}$ until I've proved uniqueness.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how systematic you're being. If you're just using matrix inverses on a homework problem in an unrelated course, it's probably unnecessary to prove uniqueness as a lemma. If you're preparing lecture notes on linear algebra, then you *should* show that the matrix $B$ with the property $AB=BA=I$ is unique if it exists. As for why, keep in mind the notation $A^{-1}$ is basically describing a function $f$ with input $A$. But when you define a new function, you ought to show that it is well-defined (if you're being conscientious about rigor, at least).

Comment: You don't need to prove uniqueness. You get that for free because if $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ both work you get that $A^{-1}=A^{-1}(AB^{-1}) = (A^{-1}A)B^{-1}=B^{-1}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma That's not "for free"; that's a proof :P

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yes, but it works for all cases so you don't have to do it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clearer thought:

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $n$-by-$n$ matrices such that $AB=I$.

Prove that $BA=I$.

Prove that if $X$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix such that $AX=I$, then $X=B$.

Now that the tasks are clearer, are you able to do them?